# how to delete every thing except notpad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

This is my code

```
{"UserId":242558405,"AbsoluteURL":"https://www.roblox.com/users/242558405/profile/","Username":"robloxpalyer9349","AvatarUri":"http://imagesak.roblox.com/325472601571f31e1bf00674c368d335.gif","AvatarFinal":true,"OnlineStatus":{"LocationOrLastSeen":"2/23/2017 10:37:05 AM","ImageUrl":"~/images/offline.png","AlternateText":"robloxpalyer9349 is offline (last seen at 2/23/2017 10:37:05 AM."},"Thumbnail":{"Final":true,"Url":"http://imagesak.roblox.com/325472601571f31e1bf00674c368d335.gif","RetryUrl":null,"UserId":242558405,"EndpointType":"Avatar"},"InvitationId":0,"LastLocation":"Offline","PlaceId":null,"AbsolutePlaceURL":null,"IsOnline":false,"InGame":false,"InStudio":false,"IsFollowed":false,"FriendshipStatus":3,"IsDeleted":false},{"UserId":170660795,"AbsoluteURL":"https://www.roblox.com/users/170660795/profile/","Username":"Robloxplayer8348","AvatarUri":"http://imagesak.roblox.com/325472601571f31e1bf00674c368d335.gif","AvatarFinal":true,"OnlineStatus":{"LocationOrLastSeen":"2/20/2018 11:56:41 PM","ImageUrl":"~/images/offline.png","AlternateText":"Robloxplayer8348 is offline (last seen at 2/20/2018 11:56:41 PM."},"Thumbnail":{"Final":true,"Url":"http://imagesak.roblox.com/325472601571f31e1bf00674c368d335.gif","RetryUrl":null,"UserId":170660795,"EndpointType":"Avatar"},"InvitationId":0,"LastLocation":"Offline","PlaceId":null,"AbsolutePlaceURL":null,"IsOnline":false,"InGame":false,"InStudio":false,"IsFollowed":false,"FriendshipStatus":3,"IsDeleted":false},
```

it is alot bigger than this
i want it only to be the id near userId:
it should look like this

```
242558405
170660795
```

Comment: For me its unclear what you are trying to do / achieve.
Searching for exactly 9 digits for example works like this:
```\d{9}```

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `.+?"UserId":(\d+)`
- Replace with: `$1\n`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
.+?         : 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
"UserId"    : literally
(           : start group 1
  \d+       : 1 or more digits
)           : end group
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      : content of group 1
\n      : linefeed, you may change it into \r\n
```

**Result for given example:**

```
242558405
242558405
170660795
170660795
,"EndpointType":"Avatar"},"InvitationId":0,"LastLocation":"Offline","PlaceId":null,"AbsolutePlaceURL":null,"IsOnline":false,"InGame":false,"InStudio":false,"IsFollowed":false,"FriendshipStatus":3,"IsDeleted":false},
```

After this first step, you have to delete manually the last line.
Then it gives:

```
242558405
242558405
170660795
170660795
```